# How to get a list of countries that are shown in google map's view port?

Tags: google-maps

For example , I have this map zoomed in on an area in [southeast asia](https://maps.google.com/?ll=12.511665,116.542969&spn=24.319247,43.022461&t=h&z=5)

Given that zoom level, i'd like to get all the countries that are currently being shown? Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=11.562038&lng=117.153352&zoom=5&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/world_countries_kml.xml), which lists the polygons in view in the sidebar:

That example is implemented with geoxml3 and KML, but it seems like you might be able do do something similar with FusionTables (the Natural Earth data set contains country polygons and is publicly available).

Comment: wow! i like how the right panel for countries dynamically change in accordance with the map!